# Python strptime returns ValueError for apparent valid format

Tags: python, date

The following date is returning a value error for what appears to be a valid datetime string.   Why?

```
from datetime import datetime

dateFormat = "%A %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p"
myDateStr = "Sunday May 22, 2016 00:47 AM"

try:
    date_object = datetime.strptime(myDateStr,dateFormat)
    print(date_object)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

I will admit to being slightly confused.   It's been tested on two platforms and does generally work.

Thanks

For the benefit of the reader here are the format masks.

- %A        Weekday as locale’s full name. Sunday, Monday, ..., Saturday (en_US);
- %b (%B)   Month as locale’s abbreviated name. Jan, Feb, ..., Dec (en_US);
- %d        Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number, 01, 02, ..., 31
- %Y        Year with century as a decimal number. 1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
- %I        Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, ..., 12
- %M        Minute as a zero-padded decimal number. 00, 01, ..., 59
- %p       Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. AM, PM (en_US);

Comment: "does generally work" So what is the problem?

Comment: shouldn't the format string be `'%A %b %d, %Y %H:%M %p'` which works for me?

Comment: where's the traceback?

Comment: So generally work means that it has been working for other dates until now(ish).  I don't know exactly what date over the last few weeks it stopped working.  It relies on a remote source but this is the most current date it seems stuck on.

Comment: The only error I get is:   time data 'Sunday May 22, 2016 00:47 AM' does not match format '%A %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p'

Comment: Yes, you are right %H makes this work but I'm sure that previous dates have been in the 12hour format.    I'll have to switch and see what occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `%I` which as you said is 12-hour format, yet you use 24-hour format in your string, ie `00:47`.

`00:47 AM` is not a valid time specification in any format.

Changing `00:47 AM` to `12:47 AM`, or `%I` to `%H`, fixes this issue.

Comment: You are right.  My fear is that the source I'm using which I have no control over is using a mash up of 12/24 format.  Hey-ho.

Comment: @Davies-Barnard Then you can first try with `%I`, then in the except block use `%H`.